# Long Script Still Being Executed But Drupal Form Engine "Gives Up"

Tags: php, performance, drupal

I have a page that has a long execution time. I am able to verify that it is actually working.  The page does not generaete any errors, however it does not display the output of the form.  Rather it reverts to the empty form that it started out with.  If I ask the form to process less, the process works.

How would I go about troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the watchdog log or make sure that Error reporting is set to **Write errors to the log and to the screen** on the *Error reporting* page (under Admin > Site configuration). If that doesn't turn anything up, check your web server log. It sounds like you might need to adjust the max_execution_time.

Comment: OK, I don't have any real errors in the log.  Would I need to do it site wide or just for the script?  The way drupal works, there is one hook calling another.  If I wanted to adjust to adjust max time for just this module, would I embed it in each script?  The thing that is really tricky is that the script now seems to finish executing and the end result shows up where it needs to, however the results of the form, "drupal style" don't show up.

Comment: This wasn't the answer per say but was a valid suggestion.  Real deal was something else that I couldn't pin down but I was able to get it working by adjusting other stuff.